# Detecting ellipses in an image

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

I’m trying to use CNNs to detect ellipses (of different shapes, sizes, orientation) in an image.
How do I do this?
I’ve tried using many centered ellipses as training (positive) examples and noise as negative examples. (It didn’t work in detecting a simple test ellipse).
My concern is that a CNN captures features/kernels/filters (like rounded edges) from the training examples. But a curved edge captures little information regarding an ellipse.
Can one SET ellipses as features/kernels/filters in a CNN?
(Matlab answer preferred)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use multiple curved filters with different curves. eg a longer curve for the longer parts of an eclipse and a shorter curve for the shorter parts

Comment: Thks. But I don’t think that captures the essence of an ellipse. All the curves have to be connected. 
But can one set filters? (ie, to be an ellipse!!)